# Clang takes very long time to compile LLVM IR large arrays

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am trying to compile LLVM IR code that contains a few large arrays (400 elements). When I try to compile this with clang (not run, just compile) - it takes longer than 10 minutes.

#### IR Code

```
define i32 @main() {
  %j = alloca double
  %i = alloca double
  %foo = alloca [400 x double]
  %B = alloca [400 x [400 x double]]
  %A = alloca [400 x [400 x double]]
  %1 = insertvalue [400 x double] undef, double 0.000000e+00, 0
  %2 = insertvalue [400 x [400 x double]] undef, [400 x double] %1, 0
  store [400 x [400 x double]] %2, [400 x [400 x double]]* %A
  %3 = insertvalue [400 x double] undef, double 0.000000e+00, 0
  %4 = insertvalue [400 x double] undef, double 0.000000e+00, 0
  %5 = insertvalue [400 x [400 x double]] undef, [400 x double] %4, 0
  store [400 x [400 x double]] %5, [400 x [400 x double]]* %B
  %6 = insertvalue [400 x double] undef, double 0.000000e+00, 0
  store [400 x double] %6, [400 x double]* %foo
  store double 0.000000e+00, double* %i

  ret i32 0
}
```

Command to run: `clang out.ll -o built`

#### Edit

I think this has to do with clang trying to create the arrays or something. As I make bigger arrays, clang builds take longer but, running the programs takes about the same amount of time. It does not really make sense to me why this would happen but, it does appear to be what is happening.

#### Versions

LLVM: `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)`

Clang: `clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)`

(added from comments)
How do I make this take less time? ... It seems weird that it would take this long. I know there is a way to make it take less time because, for example, C is able to make arrays that big and it will compile in no time.

#### Edit 2

I tried implementing `malloc` in order to have the arrays allocated on the heap instead of the stack. Here is some new IR Code. My question is where is this being allocated? When I generate multidimensional arrays it is still really slow - in that case how would I speed it up again?

```
%foo = alloca [400 x [400 x double]]
%calltmp1 = call i8* @malloc(i64 10240000)
%4 = bitcast i8* %calltmp1 to [400 x [400 x double]]*

%5 = getelementptr [400 x [400 x double]], [400 x [400 x double]]* %4, i32 0, i32 0

%calltmp2 = call i8* @malloc(i64 25600)
%6 = bitcast i8* %calltmp2 to [400 x double]*

%7 = getelementptr [400 x double], [400 x double]* %6, i32 0, i32 0
store double 1.000000e+00, double* %7
%8 = getelementptr [400 x double], [400 x double]* %6, i32 0, i32 1
store double 1.000000e+00, double* %8
%9 = getelementptr [400 x double], [400 x double]* %6, i32 0, i32 1
store double 1.000000e+00, double* %9

%initialized_array3 = load [400 x double], [400 x double]* %6
store [400 x double] %initialized_array3, [400 x double]* %5

%initialized_array4 = load [400 x [400 x double]], [400 x [400 x double]]* %4
store [400 x [400 x double]] %initialized_array4, [400 x [400 x double]]* %foo
```

#### Edit 3

Sorry for all the edits but, I think the extra info is helpful.

Here is some more IR Code I generated:

```
  %foo = alloca [400 x [400 x double]]
  store [400 x [400 x double]] undef, [400 x [400 x double]]* %foo

  %0 = getelementptr [400 x [400 x double]], [400 x [400 x double]]* %foo, i32 0, i32 0
  %1 = getelementptr [400 x double], [400 x double]* %0, i32 0, i32 0
  store double 1.598000e+03, double* %1
```

This is **almost** identical to this IR Code generated form `c`:

```
  %1 = alloca [400 x [400 x i32]], align 16
  %2 = alloca i32*, align 8
  %3 = getelementptr inbounds [400 x [400 x i32]], [400 x [400 x i32]]* %1, i64 0, i64 0
  %4 = getelementptr inbounds [400 x i32], [400 x i32]* %3, i64 0, i64 0
  store i32 1, i32* %4, align 16
```

However, the `c` code compiles in less than a second and mine takes too long to even be able to tell. This is because of line 2 in the first code snippet (below for reference). Why does that cause clang to run so slowly?

Line slowing it down:

```
store [400 x [400 x double]] undef, [400 x [400 x double]]* %foo
```

Comment: What is your clang+llvm version? Can you post full out.ll to test it? You may try some kind of profiling (with linux `perf record`/`perf report` or even with `gdb --args clang out.ll -o built`, then `run`, wait a minute, ctrl-c and `bt`) to get idea of which part of clang is working.

Comment: @osgx I appreciate your help! The above code is the whole out.ll file. I will update the post with clang+llvm version in one sec. I will see if I can do some profiling and then check back here (might be tomorrow morning though).

Comment: @osgx just updated my question - not sure if that is what you are looking for (pretty new to cpp) - let me know if I can/should do anything else. Again, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Not sure about gdb (having a hard time getting it to work on sierra) but I *think* I got backtrace working (see updated question).

Comment: This is backtrace of some thread waiting for something. There should e some thread (or process) which doing some useful or not-so-useful work. Can you check other threads or profiler (Instruments?). Ok, I have perf with linux and clang 4.0, top function is `llvm::SDNode::hasNUsesOfValue`, and second is `llvm::SelectionDAG::ReplaceAllUsesOfValueWith`. 9 seconds for all sizes changed to 100; more than 4 minutes for size 200 (is there some quadratic algorithm? is it stack protector?). What is your real question? You should change from local stack storage to heap memory which is safer.

Comment: My real question is how do I make this take less time. I am not exactly sure what you are asking with the quadratic algorithm or profiling other threads. It seems weird that it would take this long. I know there is a way to make it take less time because, for example, C is able to make arrays that big and it will compile in no time.

Comment: Is your ll code correct? (resulting `build` has no useful actions inside main function.) The `clang out.ll -o built` command is full parse+optimize(?)+backend+link command, you can try to split it into separate stages (`-v` option of clang will show what are real commands working, some may be split into llvm subcommands like opt), and find which stage (optimization or backend) takes most time. With C arrays are usually allocated with malloc/free (and new/delete in C++, both on heap), not with alloca (on stack). Can you post full algorithm in ll or in C code?

Comment: I will try that. I am not sure what you mean by full algorithm. I just copy/past the above code into a file and compile it with clang. It takes a **long** time. That is what I want to fix. (I might be mistaken but,) I think clang should not allocate the memory, that should happen when I run the program, right? Thanks again for the help. also thanks for updating the question to make it more clear.

Comment: How did you write the ll code? Current version of code is fully optimized down to several stack allocations; and it doesn't calculate anything useful (And this optimization in clang/llvm takes time). To make it faster use arrays in heap, not on stack (call malloc function, don't use alloca builtin for huge arrays).

Comment: Thanks. That is super helpful. This is a small snippet of an issue that I got from a larger file that was generated with the llvm-cpp api.

Comment: I had a similar issue when writing my backend. What I did instead was calling malloc in an external function returning memory for the array that way. I do not know about your scenario, but maybe you can do the same thing?

Comment: Thanks @JKT that is probably what I will do.

Comment: @JKT using `malloc` sped it up significantly, but it still cannot do multidimensional arrays above about `60` elements.

Comment: @pudility What I did to be more precise was that I saved my entire array in the existing IR. I then used the foreign function interface to pass the entire raw array to C (During the LLVM-IR generation phase) where I created the array assigned all the elements to it. I then allocated a pointer to the array data using the runtime systems garbage collector, then I returned a reference to my LLVM pointer. Would something similar be possible for you to do?

Comment: @JKT I see. That is pretty smart - If I cant get it working with just the C++ LLVM API I think that is what I will do. Thanks for the suggestion and clarity.

Comment: @pudility I only made use of the C++ api. However, I did implement some external C functions in my runtime. The array was created on the heap and the specified pointer to the array (that was created during the traversal of my IR) was specified to the LLVM pointer designated to hold the array. Still you may need to have a garbage collection of some sort in your language for this to be a feasible solution.

Comment: @JKT Thanks. I also have a few external C functions, its more about trying to figure this out for me. But I agree, that might be a more practical option.